# I'm not able to boot into Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysIUT.jpg)
PC:DELL Inspiron 3000 series
I had my PC dual booted with windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I was running out of space and I unknowingly deleted the Windows partition along with a few Linux ones. I installed another version of Ubuntu in the available space and I am able to see all my files by accessing it through the drive.
I am quite new to Linux any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Because of a lot of changes, we need details. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: The first thing I would do in your shoes - as someone fairly new to Linux - is boot into a live usb session and *copy all the data you want to keep to an external drive* - then try to solve your problem. It may well be simplest to reinstall - and then copy your data back over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)